# Copying docker host files from host to local - is it possible?

Tags: command-line, docker

```
# docker exec -it id bash
```

By this command we can move inside a container and find files in it.
Inside this how can we write a python script or shell script so the files inside this will move to local. When ever a new file is being generated.

Comment: And more importantly, what are you trying to achieve? Why not use persistent volumes?

Comment: @Artur Meinild Thanks for formatting  - i didn't see the question. The answer is to create an persistent volume and a CMD entry in your dockerfile. The python script needs to be copied into your container with the COPY command. [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Comment: this seems a pretty unclear question. the command `docker cp <source> <destination>` might be too easy as answer.

Comment: can you help with python script or shell script

Comment: Please explain what your purpose is, before anyone uses time for something that might be in vain.. Why do you need to copy data from your container to the system?

Comment: Without switching the path i want to view the files present in it.